# When uploading a file using <input> element to a C# asp.net server side, how can the C# access file attributes like file size or file type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `<input>` element file chooser that allows a user to select a file for upload.  As soon as the file is selected, it is uploaded to the windows server 2008 and written to disk in a Windows temporary folder. The serverside code is written in C#.

My question: As the file is transferred to the server, is there a way to access attributes of the file being uploaded such as the file size or file type from within C# server code? Would I be able to grab it from an HttpWebRequest or an HttpMultiPartWebRequest or something?

I would appreciate all / any suggestions from the asp.net community.

Comment: as a note mime type is a guess based on browser and webserver info.  It my not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on uploading a file in C# using a Web Form:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323246

Obtaining information about the file itself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Here are some relevant parts from that second linked article:

> "You can use the `ContentLength` property to get the length of the file. You can use the `ContentType` property to get the MIME content type of the file. In addition, you can use the `PostedFile` property to access the `FileName` property, the `InputStream` property, and the `SaveAs` method. However, the same functionality is provided by the `FileName` property, the `FileContent` property, and the `SaveAs` method."

Comment: Would it be possible to append a custom file attribute? For example, how would I add an attribute "color" to each uploaded file? A color could be "red", "orange", "yellow", or "green".

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve; in this context, what does a file color signify? You could add an attribute in the Page_Init event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx

Comment: it doesnt signify much except when a file is uploaded I want to associate all files with colors. These colors will be stored in the database in something like a hash map (uploadedfiles->color)

Comment: Basically, i want to tag each file with a special string that represents a name of a color.

Comment: I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927520/how-can-i-add-my-own-custom-file-attributes-to-a-http-multi-part-form-in-asp-net