# How can I add my own custom file attributes to a http multi part form in asp.net C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have successfully created a C# project using the WebSite template within Visual Studio 2015.  I modified "Default.aspx" to contain:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"   />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" PostBackUrl=".upl"/>
```

I also modified Default.aspx.cs to look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the Class Library template to create a DLL/Handler in order to intercept upload file web requests as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Web;


namespace WebRequestInterceptorModule
{
    public class Class1 : IHttpHandler
    {


    public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = request.Params;

            string test = "hello";

            // Example #4: Append new text to an existing file.
            // The using statement automatically flushes AND CLOSES the stream and calls 
            // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object.
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dining Room\Documents\WriteLines2.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(test);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I successfully registered the above handler by modifying web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>

    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      <add name="mytest" verb="*" path=".upl"  type="WebRequestInterceptorModule.Class1"/>
    </handlers>
```

and I know the handler is indeed intercepting upload requests because I see a file "WriteLines" generated every time I perform an upload.

So to summarize, file uploads are working correctly and I am able to successfully intercept file upload requests using a handler/DLL.

My question for the community is: Suppose I want to append a custom string attribute along with file that is being uploaded (i.e. something like a commment "these are important notes from last week") how can I do that?

In order to try to answer my own question I attempted to place a breakpoint in my handler itself and debug the "request" object.  Here is what I see:

[image]

I see something called "QueryString" which happens to be the empty string ("").  Is it possible I can put my comment in there? If so, how do I need to modify Default.apsx in order to update the QueryString?

Comment: Just add field to your form

Comment: You can add whatever fields you like to your HTML form, which can contain whatever data you like.

Comment: Could you please point me to an example or sample code and I will mark your answer correct

Comment: @user1068636: Any tutorial on ASP.NET is going to show how to make a form.

Comment: the problem is with tutorials like this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323246#bookmark-5 they don't show how to extract a custom file attribute. They simply show basic file uploads which I already have working

Comment: @user1068636: It's not really clear where this information is actually being stored.  Is this custom attribute actually part of the file?  Or is it simply a piece of text you want to upload along with the file?  Please clarify.  If it's part of the file, maybe it can only be stored on certain file systems?

Comment: This custom attribute is not part of the file at all. It's completely separate.  However, once both the file and the comment are transmitted to the server side, I wish to place them in the database right next to each other

Comment: @user1068636: So what is preventing that?  Adding a text field to a form is introductory ASP.NET.  Add a text input to the form and get its value in the server-side code to include when inserting into the database.  What have you tried?  What didn't work?

Comment: @David - I tried using a <div id="commentid" and value="this is my comment"> however on the server side I can't find "this is my comment" anywhere in the request.

Comment: @user1068636: A `div` isn't a form element.  You need an `input`.

Comment: the input looks like:  <input type="submit" value="Submit">.  I can't put another value= in there because value is already being set to "Submit.

Comment: @user1068636: Then add another `input`.  You can have more than one.

Comment: @David - adding another input defeats the purpose of sending the comment atomically along with the uploaded file. It sounds like you're suggesting to send the file first, and then send the comment in a different request. This is not acceptable for me.

Comment: @user1068636: Nowhere did I suggest that you perform multiple requests.  HTML forms can have multiple inputs.  Yours already has two, one of type "submit" and one of type "file".  Why do you assume it can't have a third?  Please start with an introductory tutorial on ASP.NET.  Creating a form is covered in any introductory tutorial.

Comment: Just add a custom attribute to the file input (make sure to have the runat="server" set). Then just retrieve the custom attribute value on the server side using basic dot notation.

Comment: @David and IrishChieftain - I have modified my question to include more details.  Would greatly appreciate if you could take a crack at this one more time.

Comment: @user1068636: Why not just add a `TextBox` to the page?  It's still not clear how what you're trying to do is different from just having another input on the page for text.

Comment: @David - I want the comment to be hidden, so I don't want to use a TextBox.

Comment: @user1068636: Then use a `Hidden` instead?  (Of course, like any client-side content it can still be modified by a savvy user, but it won't be displayed on the page.)

Comment: ok, but how do I actually access the hidden comment in the request object? Where does this hidden field get stashed?

Comment: I added a snapshot of the request object at a debug breakpoint for your viewing convenience

Comment: @user1068636: This is where you should *really* be starting with an introductory tutorial on ASP.NET.  The entire technology is centered around building forms.  At a high level, page control values are accessible from the controls themselves on the page, or you can get raw form data from `Request.Form`.